# CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() returns a wrong value

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I use a CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() to get current time, but it returns a wrong value, below zero or just 2001-01-01 08:00:00 which is 506520688.48152697 in double, I run on a simulator and an iPhoneSE, the same error.

`let time: CFAbsoluteTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()`

that is my code. runs in main thread and on Xcode 8.2.1 and 8.1.

Thank You.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue. I would strongly suspect that you're looking at something other than `time` or printing it out incorrectly. Do you have a small, complete sample that demonstrates?

Comment: `506520688.48152697` is `2017-01-19 12:11:28 +0000`, that looks reasonable.

Comment: 506520688.48152697 is today (19 jan 2017). Please check your date formatter :)

Comment: sorry, my bad , i thought it is since 1970 and didn't check it carefully, my bad, :)

Answer (score 1):

CFAbsoluteTime does not return the current time, it returns the difference time between the reference date of `1 Jan 2001 00:00:00 GMT` and your current date.

`506520688.48152697` is the number of seconds between the reference date and the specified date (in case, its your current date).

Comment: sorry, I thought it is since 1970, :)